# SQL select depending on last access date

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to make a select from a table, but I only need those rows, which were changed in the last 24hrs.

The select should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE {row last change date > current date/time - 24hrs}
```

I can't use any external file to store the last database state and compare it to current state (row by row), because the amount of data which I work with is enormous. Also I can't alter the tables to add a column with the date of the last change - the database is created by a 3rd party software.. I only need to extract data from it.

Any ideas how to get the rows which were changed over the last day?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a column that indicates the time of when a row was changed, and is it a key?

Comment: no, unfortunately :( I just edited that info to the question..

Comment: then there is no way to do it, either store the update_date or you can't make such a query

Comment: can you create a trigger?

Comment: no, I can only use selects.. isn't this type of info stored somewhere?

Comment: It's a lot of work, but you could make a full copy of this table every day, and compare yesterday's copy to the live version to see which rows have changed since the copy was made.  (Or possibly there's some trick using [snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx) - ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't edit that table add a table inside the db with 2 columns:

```
ID int NOT NULL,
last_modified datetime NOT NULL
```

and add a foreign key on ID on primary key of your table

Comment: I see where you are going with this.. But the change is triggered from the 3rd party software.. I would have to rewrite their application to update the new table, or am I wrong? Am I able to automatically update the new table when some other table changes?

Comment: You should also edit the code of the application, in the place where it stores the modify on database you should add another query. You may use an observer to store the last_modified date, adding a new module without changing source code. But I don't know if you can modify source code